# Скачать файл с сервера nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular

У меня есть сайт на nginx + nodejs + angular. Хотелось бы, чтобы нажимая на кнопку, скачивался файл с моего debian сервера.
Как это лучше сделать? Так как файл имеет вес 210мб, расширение .zip

Answer (score 0):

В общем оказалось несложно

Nodejs

```
app.get('/download', function(req, res){
 const file = `${__dirname}/upload-folder/my.zip`;
 res.download(file);
});
```

Angular

```
location.href = 'mysite.com/download';
```